# Node.js callback called twice

Tags: node.js, callback, coffeescript, sendgrid

I'm using the sendgrid library for node.js. Currently there is a callback that it's getting fired twice.

```
    @invite = (email, agencyId, callback) ->
  (app.get 'agencies').findOne {_id: agencyId}, {name:1}, (error, agency) ->
    sendgrid.send {
      to: email,
      from: 'yamil.asusta@upr.edu',
      subject: "You have been invited to #{agency.name}",
      html: "<html><body>Have fun</a></body></html>"
    }, (success, message) ->
      console.log arguments
      if success
        console.log callback
        callback()
      else
        console.log message
```

This is what I get from the console

```
{ '0': true, '1': undefined }
[Function]
{ '0': false, '1': 'Invalid JSON response from server' }
Invalid JSON response from server
```

The thing is, I invoke the function from 1 route and it works perfectly fine. If I invoke it from another separate route, it fires the callback but, it says the callback variable (function) is undefined.

Any clues?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you log the arguments to the `@invite` function. I suspect that is getting called twice, once with correct arguments and once with incorrect arguments due to a bug elsewhere in your program.

Comment: I have, several times... It gets called just once.